# How to enable resize handles on a simple MacOS window?

Tags: objective-c, macos, nswindow, appkit, window-resize

I have a very simple MacOS window, single compilation file, compiled with the clang compiler (e.g. `clang -framework AppKit -o simple-mac-window osx_main.mm`). It can be run from the command line.

```
//OSX Main - Entry point for the OSX platform.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <AppKit/AppKit.h>

static float GlobalRenderWidth = 1024;
static float GlobalRenderHeight = 768;
static bool Running = true;

//Declare an interface that inherits from NSObject and implements NSWindowDelegate.
@interface SimpleMainWindowDelegate: NSObject<NSWindowDelegate>
@end
@implementation SimpleMainWindowDelegate

- (void)windowWillClose:(id)sender {
    Running = false;
}

@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    SimpleMainWindowDelegate *mainWindowDelegate = [[SimpleMainWindowDelegate alloc] init];

    NSRect screenRect = [[NSScreen mainScreen] frame];
    NSRect initialFrame = NSMakeRect((screenRect.size.width - GlobalRenderWidth) * 0.5,
                                        (screenRect.size.height - GlobalRenderHeight) * 0.5,
                                        GlobalRenderWidth,
                                        GlobalRenderHeight);

    NSWindow *window = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect: initialFrame
                                            styleMask: NSWindowStyleMaskTitled |
                                                        NSWindowStyleMaskClosable |
                                                        NSWindowStyleMaskMiniaturizable |
                                                        NSWindowStyleMaskResizable
                                            backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
                                            defer:NO];
    [window setBackgroundColor: NSColor.redColor];
    [window setTitle:@"simple-mac-window"];
    [window makeKeyAndOrderFront: nil];
    [window setDelegate: mainWindowDelegate];

    while(Running) {
        NSEvent* event;
        do {
            event = [NSApp nextEventMatchingMask: NSEventMaskAny
            untilDate: nil
            inMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode
            dequeue: YES];

            switch([event type]) {
                default:
                [NSApp sendEvent: event];
            }
        } while (event != nil);
    }

    printf("Finished running simple-mac-window.");
}
```

I have set the `NSWindowStyleMaskResizable` flag on the `styleMask` when initialising the window. This allows me to drag and resize the window when selecting the edges of the screen. However I do not get the handles to resize the window when I move my cursor to edge of the window. What are the minimum code elements I need to add in order to support this?

I have tried checking out the [NSWindow Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow?language=objc) but it seems that all is required is the flag. Perhaps I need to set some values on the window object or update the [window delegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindowdelegate) to include something? Or is this because of the minimal approach taken to get a window running?

Comment: Just a guess, but it could be because the manual runloop doesn't handle all the necessary types or modes. An easy experiment would be trying `NSRunLoopCommonModes`

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but i'm struggling to understand how this is used from the documentation. Do you have any sample code?

Comment: It's not clear to me what your objective is. Why would you like to drive a manual runloop for an AppKit app?

Comment: I guess my objective is an application window in a single compilation unit. I am following a series on Medium because I like the work on Handmade Hero; https://medium.com/@theobendixson/how-to-make-a-video-game-100-from-scratch-starting-on-a-mac-2f9062fe7645. I'm interested in learning about the low level aspect of MacOS development works and i'm trying to understand how I can apply the documentation to a minimal example. I thought, perhaps foolishly, that enabling window resize handles was a case of my missing some setting or gonfiguration.

Comment: I believe your window object is created correctly because it can be resized using the mouse despite the absence of the resize handles. I don't know what is done internally to draw the resize handles. Reimplementing  portions of AppKit functionality at a low level is probably going to be a frustrating (rewarding?) endeavor because the framework isn't designed to be used this way so the documentation, as you've discovered, isn't always helpful. It's definitely an interesting issue to tackle!

Comment: Indeed, it might be a little silly, there is just so much code generated from the XCode samples. One thing I want to clarify; it's not just the handles, I can't actually resize the window form the edge at all. The window changes size if I double click the title bar (maximises) and then returns to the starting size if I do it again. But i can't drag and change the size. Hence why I thought it was something to do with the setup.

Comment: I'm using Catalina and clang-1103 and I can definitely drag to resize the window using your posted code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221285/discussion-between-jimmydeemo-and-sbooth).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues (at least). First, passing `nil` for the `untilDate:` parameter means your event loop spins, handling a `nil` event all the time. You should pass `[NSDate distantFuture]`.

Second, standalone executables — that is, those that are not in an app bundle — start life with an activation policy of `NSApplicationActivationPolicyProhibited`. You need to do `[NSApp setActivationPolicy:NSApplicationActivationPolicyRegular]` before your event loop.

Comment: This did it; not only do I have resize handles but the window also correctly drags to a 2nd monitor (it used to be behind other windows before). Having read the documentation I can clearly see that the policy was needed. Thank you.

Comment: Though I find that if I maintain the `distantFuture` parameter my app doesn't exit the running loop properly on close.

Comment: You should probably be using `[NSApp terminate:self]` instead of relying on the event loop to exit.